# Access this data structure [{"id":"1","name":"2"},{...}]

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Trying to access individual values from a query return:

```
$sentenceSQL=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_data");
$sentenceSQL->execute();
$result= $sentenceSQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$va = json_encode($result);
echo $va;
```

[{"id":"001","name":"john"},{"id":"002","name":"Ann"}]

From the above echo result, how can I access individual values ?

If I try :

```
$myval = $va['id'];
echo $myval;
I get : Illegal string offset 'id'
```

Could anyone please tell me how do I access the values?

Comment: Have a look at the original `$result` value instead, there is no need to `json_encode()` it to access the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you run `json_encode()` on the result, the variable `$va` will be a string, not an array.

If you want to use the values in PHP, simply don't encode it.

```
// First record
$myval = $result[0]['id'];

// Second record
$myval = $result[1]['id'];
```

...and so on.